# Laravel, Category relations posts

Tags: php, laravel

So I don't how to use posts with categories in my foreach.
Controller

```
        $Categories = \App\Category::Where('displayed',1)->get();
        foreach ($Categories as $Category){
        $CategoryPosts[]=$Category->load('posts');
        }
        dd($CategoryPosts);
        return view('welcome', compact($CategoryPosts));
```

Page

```
@forelse($CategoryPosts as $post)
         <div  id="content-number-1" class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 home-post1 content-number-1">
            <div class=""><img class="content-one-img content-img-chapter" src="{{$post->image}}"></div>
            <div class="content-text-img p-3"><p><a class="m-0 underImage aTagsHover" style="font-size: 20px" href="/inside/{{$post->id}}">{{$post->title}}</a><br><span class="date-font"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{$post->created_at}}</span><span class="underBusiness"><br>{{$post->short_desc}}</span></p></div>
        </div>
@empty
        <div  id="content-number-1" class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 home-post1 content-number-1">
            <div class="content-one-img content-img-chapter"></div>
            <div class="content-text-img p-3"><p><a class="m-0 underImage aTagsHover" style="font-size: 20px" href="#">No post</a><br><span class="date-font"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>No time</span><span class="underBusiness"><br>No post</span></p></div>
        </div>
@endforelse
```

I have 2 categories and 3 posts right there.
https://prnt.sc/ujrvxs.

Answer (score 1):

You can go at this from the other direction to only get the Posts:

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('category', function ($query) {
    $query->where('displayed', 1);
})->get();
```

Assuming you have the inverse of the relationship setup Post -> Category. This is saying get all Posts having Category where displayed equals 1.

Adjust the relationship name as needed.

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) `whereHas`

Comment: Very simple answer and cleaner

Comment: $posts = \App\Post::whereHas('category', function(Builder $query)
        {$query->where('displayed', 1)});        return view('welcome', compact($posts));
syntax error, unexpected '}'... Can't find error

Comment: @Maksym you should copy what is actually here instead of typing it out as you are missing a semicolon ;)

Comment: Yes but now All posts is like in one collection. What If I need to take a some posts like for only category Sport or Fashion not like them all in one collection

Comment: I thought I https://prnt.sc/ujrvxs. I would use @foreach(CategoryPosts[0]->posts as post), but it doesn't work

Comment: the code you have in your view shows you not wanting them grouped since you are iterating a single array ... if you want them grouped that is different ... if you want to only get posts for a single category you can filter that out in the query ... so what do you actually want? since your question shows 2 different things